# how to use utility class to start intent android

Tags: java, android, scope, android-activity

I am updating code for a company app and there are about 20 activity classes that all download a PDF and then display it using this code:

```
public void showPdf()
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Read.pdf");
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

the code is working, however it has been replicated in all 20 classes (seems very bad to me) and I would like to  put it into a single class which each activity class imports, however when I try to do this, things like `getPackageManager()` and `startActivity(intent)` no longer work.

How can I structure my class to make this happen? or am I going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PDFUtlity{
    public static void showPdf(Context context)
    {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Read.pdf");
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ///.....
      PDFUtlity.showPdf(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with your first comment to create an activity class and then subclass that for all of the other classes.  Would this static method be better practice than that?

Comment: Yes, it would. My first solution `create a class that extends Activity and implement the method in the new class and then extend that new class you created` would be a better practice in cases, when you have to override activity methods in every activity of yours, like: onBackPressed, onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState (for methods that are closely operate with Context and then in every Activity that would extends such a class you will have to call super();) But then i read you question again and realized that there is no need in such a design pattern for your problem

Answer (score 3):

> How can I structure my class to make this happen?

Step #1: Make this a static method on a utility class.

Step #2: Add `Context ctxt` as a parameter to the method.

Step #3: For methods like `getPackageManager()` and `startActivity()`, which are implemented on `Context`, call them on the passed-in `ctxt` parameter.

Step #4: Smack your wrist with a ruler for using string concatenation for creating a file path, and do it the right way.

Step #5: Get rid of the `queryIntentActivities()` code that you aren't using.

```
public static void showPdf(Context ctxt)
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/pdf/Read.pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Step #6: Have the places that are presently calling `showPdf()` call `YourUtilityClass.showPdf(this)`.

Comment: I ended up creating an activity class `ActivityDisplayPDF` and then changing each of the 20 classes to extend `ActivityDisplayPDF`.  Your answer would work also and I'm wondering which is better practice..

Comment: @Ben: Forcing inheritance is usually not a good idea for something this small. For example, what happens if you need to show this PDF from a `PreferenceActivity`? Or from a `ListActivity`? Now you either have to clone `ActivityDisplayPDF`, or you'd have to switch to my solution (or something like it).